# Symfony 4.3 - Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\BlogPost::setTitle() must be of the type string, null given

Tags: php, symfony4

I am developing simple blog with Symfony 4.3. And then when I add a new post , I found this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\BlogPost::setTitle() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\wamp64\www\symfony4\src\Controller\BlogPostController.php on line 99
```

My function see below here:

```
    public function add(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
        {

            $form = $this->createForm(BlogPostType::class);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

                $blogPost = new BlogPost();
                $blogPost->setTitle($request->request->get('title'));
                $blogPost->setContent($request->request->get('content'));
                $blogPost->setPublishedAt(new \DateTime());
                $blogPost->setUser($this->getUser());

                $entityManager->persist($blogPost);
                $entityManager->flush();

              return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('blog_post_index'));
            }

            return new Response(
                $this->twig->render(
                    'blog_post/add.html.twig',
                    ['blogPostForm' => $form->createView()]
                )
            );
        }
```

So can I set the title and content?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms

You should fetch the data from the (validated) `$form` object instead of the `$request`, so instead of `$request->request->get('title')`, you should use `$form->getData()['title']`.

Assuming you're not using `BlogPost` as a `data_class` in your form and you have proper validation setup.